# Property not being recognized in custom cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Here is my CustomCoordinatesCell.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CoordinatesCustomCell : UITableViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *index;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *latitude;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *longitude;
@end
```

However, in my CustomCoordinatesCell.m file, when I use @synthesize for latitude and longitude for example, @synthesize latitude = _latitude, this works. However, when I try this for the index property, it gives me an error:

Property implementation must have its declaration in interface 'CoordinatesCustomCell'

However, the property for index IS in my CoordinatesCustomCell.h file

Here is my CustomCoordinateCell.m file:

```
#import "CoordinatesCustomCell.h"

@implementation CoordinatesCustomCell
@synthesize latitude = _latitude;
@synthesize longitude = _longitude;
@synthesize index = _index;

//@synthesize coordinateNumber = _coordinateNumber;
- (void)awakeFromNib {
// Initialization code
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
[super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

// Configure the view for the selected state
}

@end
```

Comment: You haven't needed @synthesize statements for many years. Delete them

Comment: well, i normally use swift but i had to do some coding in objective c. I tried just using the using the properties in the cell identifier method in the table view controller class, and the properties wouldn't show up. I dont really know how to do this with objective c

Comment: like if i do cell.latitude, the latitude property doesnt show up

Comment: Did you #import "CoordinatesCustomCell.h" in your tableview controller class ?

Comment: yes, and it wouldnt let me access the properties

Comment: you are declaring your cell to be a subclass of `UITableViewController` but it should be `UITableViewCell`

Comment: lol that was dumb. I changed it to the TableViewCell

Comment: it still is not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114075/discussion-between-paulw11-and-nilay-neeranjun).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You no longer need `@synthesize` statements.

You have accidentally declared your cell as subclassing `UITableViewController` rather than `UITableViewCell`.

Also make sure that you declare and cast your `cell` correctly in order to access its custom properties:

```
CustomCoordinateCell *cell = (CustomCoordinateCell *)[tableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifiee:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```